# SQL parameter in where clause that allows for all, specific, or multiple values

Tags: sql-server-2008, parameters, where-clause, in-clause

In SQL Server 2008 I need to be able to pass in a parameter that allows for all values, specific values, or multiple values.
Below sql works fine when the parameter is "All".  And works fine with a single value.  But with multiple values I get 
"Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."
I've tried a number of things but not getting it.

```html
--Works fine
Declare @sql varchar(8000)
,@p_CODE varchar(100)
,@v_CODE VARCHAR(100)
Set @p_CODE = ('''All''')
Set @v_CODE = @p_CODE
select @sql = 'SELECT distinct
 CODE
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE '+@v_CODE+' in ('+'''All'''+')
  or CODE in ('+@v_CODE+')'
Execute (@sql)
--Returns all records 
 
 
--Works fine  
Declare @sql varchar(8000)
,@p_CODE varchar(100)
,@v_CODE VARCHAR(100)
Set @p_CODE = ('''ABCD''')
Set @v_CODE = @p_CODE
select @sql = 'SELECT distinct
 CODE
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE '+@v_CODE+' in ('+'''All'''+')
  or CODE in ('+@v_CODE+')'
Execute (@sql)  
--Returns records with ABCD


--Returns error as noted
Declare @sql varchar(8000)
,@p_CODE varchar(100)
,@v_CODE VARCHAR(100)
Set @p_CODE = ('''ABCD'',''EFGH''')
Set @v_CODE = @p_CODE
select @sql = 'SELECT distinct
 CODE
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE '+@v_CODE+' in ('+'''All'''+')
  or CODE in ('+@v_CODE+')'
Execute (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

The left side of an IN should be an Expression, but your code made it not, it is:

```
SELECT distinct
    CODE
    FROM    TABLE 
    WHERE   'ABCD','EFGH' in ('All')
        or CODE in ('ABCD','EFGH')
```

Which you can see it is your first in has the problem not the second.

You need to change you code logic like:

```
Declare @sql varchar(8000)
,@v_CODE VARCHAR(100)
select @sql = 'SELECT distinct
    CODE
    FROM    TABLE 
    ' + CASE WHEN @v_CODE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' WHERE CODE in ('+@v_CODE+')' END

Execute (@sql)
```

And also I believe there are some better way to perform this. If the collection is too big the IN may cause performance issue.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but this doesn't return any results, and it should...
    `Declare @sql varchar(8000)
,@p_CODE varchar(100)
,@v_CODE VARCHAR(100)
Set @p_CODE = ('''ABCD'',''EFGH''')
Set @v_CODE = @p_CODE
select @sql = 'SELECT distinct
 CODE
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE CODE IS NULL OR CODE in ('+@v_CODE+')
 '
Execute (@sql)

I also need to be able to return all results.  Thx

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and clearly I was not in a clear mind. :) I've modified the answer and please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works (just reverse the in)...

```
Declare @sql varchar(8000)
,@p_CODE varchar(100)
,@v_CODE VARCHAR(100)
Set @p_CODE = ('''ABCD'',''EFGH''')
Set @v_CODE = @p_CODE
select @sql = 'SELECT distinct
    CODE
    FROM    TABLE 
    WHERE   CODE in ('+@v_CODE+')
        OR (''All'' in ('+@v_CODE+')
            AND CODE in (SELECT DISTINCT
                            CODE
                            FROM TABLE ))'
Execute (@sql)
```